# IIS7 windows identity name

Tags: iis-7

Trying to make an app that relies on the windows login name of the user, but not sure how I get that working in IIS7, it's not to use it for authentication/login purposes for my app, there is no such thing in what I'm building.

Normally within my code I'd use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, with my current IIS config it's returning `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` as the value.

Any ideas on what I need to change to get what I'm expecting?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: You are going to have Windows-only clients attaching to a web application (via IIS) but they do not need to log in. That is, you expect that Kerberos etc. will be set correctly, no non-bound clients will be hitting the app--and you just want to grab that information from the session. Is that right?

Comment: Hi Johnnie, that's right, it's an internal application for the workplace, anyone connecting to it, by default, will be logged into the work network, that's the only way the url it'll be hosted on is accessible

Answer (score 1):

If it's showing the IUSR, then anonymous authentication is kicking in.  If you want it password protected then remove anonymous access for the folder(s) that you want users to authenticate.  Then, in a domain it will authenticate with their windows account as long as their account is granted access, or in a non-domain it will ask for credentials.